# mediaReaderRandomAccessReaderClass issue with wowza restful api

Tags: api, rest, wowza

I am using WowzaStreamingEngine 4.4.1 at Ubuntu 14.04. I used restful api and created vod application (restful_vod) as in examples, it didn't work didn't stream vod files. That's why, I compare application.xml files of default vod application and restful_vod application. There is a difference between MediaReader properties. Default vod application has no property at there but restful_vod has below:

```
<MediaReader>
  <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaReaders.xml for any MediaReaders loaded by this applications -->
  <Properties>
    <Property>
      <Name>randomAccessReaderClass</Name>
      <Value></Value>
      <Type>String</Type>
    </Property>
  </Properties>
</MediaReader>
```

When I removed randomAccessReaderClass named property, it started to work. I realized mediaReaderRandomAccessReaderClass parameter manage its value at restful api side. But I couldn't find a way to prevent adding it while using restful api. I tried not setting mediaReaderRandomAccessReaderClass value and also setting mediaReaderRandomAccessReaderClass false, null and empty string.

Is there any way to prevent adding it or a default working value for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default mediaReaderRandomAccessReaderClass by setting it as follows:
"mediaReaderRandomAccessReaderClass": ""

In your resulting Application.xml file, the MediaReader container would then be blank, which would indicate that it would use the default value:

```
<MediaReader>
    <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaReaders.xml for any MediaReaders loaded by this applications -->
    <Properties>
    </Properties>
</MediaReader>
```

A working REST API command to create a VOD file, for example, would look like this.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testvod -d'
{
   "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testvod",
   "version": "1462342478287",
   "name": "testvod",
   "appType": "VOD",
   "description": "Test VOD via REST.",
   "applicationTimeout": 0,
   "pingTimeout": 0,
   "repeaterQueryString": "",
   "clientStreamReadAccess": "*",
   "avSyncMethod": "senderreport",
   "maxRTCPWaitTime": 12000,
   "httpStreamers": [
      "cupertinostreaming",
      "smoothstreaming",
      "sanjosestreaming",
      "mpegdashstreaming"
   ],
   "mediaReaderRandomAccessReaderClass": "",
   "httpOptimizeFileReads": false,
   "mediaReaderBufferSeekIO": false,
   "captionLiveIngestType": "",
   "vodTimedTextProviders": [
      "vodcaptionprovidermp4_3gpp"
   ],
   "securityConfig": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testvod/security",
      "secureTokenVersion": 0,
      "clientStreamWriteAccess": "*",
      "publishRequirePassword": true,
      "publishPasswordFile": "",
      "publishRTMPSecureURL": "",
      "publishIPBlackList": "",
      "publishIPWhiteList": "",
      "publishBlockDuplicateStreamNames": false,
      "publishValidEncoders": "",
      "publishAuthenticationMethod": "digest",
      "playMaximumConnections": 0,
      "playRequireSecureConnection": false,
      "secureTokenSharedSecret": "",
      "secureTokenUseTEAForRTMP": false,
      "secureTokenIncludeClientIPInHash": false,
      "secureTokenHashAlgorithm": "",
      "secureTokenQueryParametersPrefix": "",
      "secureTokenOriginSharedSecret": "",
      "playIPBlackList": "",
      "playIPWhiteList": "",
      "playAuthenticationMethod": "none"
   },
   "streamConfig": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testvod/streamconfiguration",
      "streamType": "default",
      "storageDir": "${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/content",
      "createStorageDir": false,
      "storageDirExists": true,
      "keyDir": "${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/keys",
      "httpRandomizeMediaName": false
   },
   "modules": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testvod/modules",
      "moduleList": [
         {
            "order": 0,
            "name": "base",
            "description": "Base",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleCore"
         },
         {
            "order": 1,
            "name": "logging",
            "description": "Client Logging",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleClientLogging"
         },
         {
            "order": 2,
            "name": "flvplayback",
            "description": "FLVPlayback",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleFLVPlayback"
         },
         {
            "order": 3,
            "name": "ModuleCoreSecurity",
            "description": "Core Security Module for Applications",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.security.ModuleCoreSecurity"
         }
      ]
   }
}'
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried it before but interestingly, setting empty string works now. Thanks anyway.